# HTML5 <video> tag controls not showing up in Android Webview

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I am creating an Android app for my mobile website using Android Webview. Everything is working fine except the HTML5 video tag, the controls are not showing up in the video in Webview but it is absolutely working fine in the mobile website. My video tag starts with `<video controls ...>`

I am testing the app on Android 5.0.2 also the website is based on Ruby on Rails with HAML as template rendering language.

Comment: Hi RSB, did manage to solve the problem by any chance? If so, could you please share the solution here?